# How to structure a simple Dart web app

Tags: dart

For Dart starters I'm working on a simple web which consists of less than 10 classes. I'm totally confused as for how to organized them in files, folders (and packages? and libraries?).

Currently I have

```
web/
  img/
    *.png
  styles/
    main.css
  index.html
  main.dart
  *.dart
```

All but one Dart file contain a single class. Imports are done through `import 'a.dart';` (e.g. in `b.dart`).

This is obviously wrong because the Dart Editor complains about

> The imported libraries 'c.dart' and 'd.dart' should not have the same
>   name ''

I went through the respective sections in [pub documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html) and read about [possible app structures](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/app-directories.html#possible-app-structures) in the Polymer docs. I also looked at the structure of the pop_pop_win sample application that comes with Dart. It's all a bit overwhelming because there are so many variations, options and combinations.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695634/warning-that-imported-libraries-have-the-same-name-when-they-do-not. It sounds like this is your real issue, not any problem with folder structure.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I got that right I can add `library foo; part 'a.dart';...` to `main.dart` and then add `part of foo;` to the other Dart files. Works, but means I have to have _all_ imports in `main.dart` because part files can't have individual imports...not nice. Or I can add `library X;` to each Dart file. That's even worse because 1 class in 1 file doesn't make a "library" yet. Hhhmm, I feel there must be a better way...

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would create libraries and imports like so:

**awesomeLibrary.dart**

```
library awesome;

part 'foo.dart';
part 'bar.dart';
```

**foo.dart**

```
part of awesome;

class Foo
{
    static function Baz() {}
}
```

**bar.dart**

```
part of awesome;

class Bar
{
    ...
}
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'awesomeLibrary.dart';

void main()
{
    Foo.Baz();  // Imported library function
}
```