# How to reference classes from another project

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to share objects between a client-side and server-side project. Currently the way I thought of doing it was by adding a 3rd project called "shared" and put my common classes inside.

But now when I run my client-side-project by referencing files like this:

`import '../../../shared/game.dart';`

I get a warning from pub saying

> [Error from InjectorGenerator on
>   client|web/main.dart]: Could not load asset
>   client|../shared/game.dart

Is there a way to either publish locally my shared project to reference the classes with the `import packages:...` syntax? Otherwise, what's the way of doing this in Dart?

Comment: Try reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951989/how-to-reference-another-file-in-dart

Comment: @PixelElephant thanks, it's indeed what I needed.