# How to use Functions of another File in Dart / Flutter?

Tags: function, methods, dart, flutter

I have a Flutter app where I'm using the flutter_web_view package.  I'm using it over several different files and would love to create its own file and simply reference with the _launchwebview function anywhere in my app because there are several lines of code needed in order to make it work.  I know how to reference files and pass information but not methods/functions.  Here is the class code...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_view/flutter_web_view.dart';

class ShopClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ShopClassState createState() => new ShopClassState();
}

class ShopClassState extends State<ShopClass> {
  String _redirectedToUrl;
  FlutterWebView flutterWebView = new FlutterWebView();
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget leading;
    if (_isLoading) {
      leading = new CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    var columnItems = <Widget>[
      new MaterialButton(
          onPressed: launchWebViewExample, child: new Text("Launch"))
    ];
    if (_redirectedToUrl != null) {
      columnItems.add(new Text("Redirected to $_redirectedToUrl"));
    }
    var app = new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          leading: leading,
        ),
        body: new Column(
          children: columnItems,
        ),
      ),
    );
    return app;
  }


  void launchWebViewExample() {
    if (flutterWebView.isLaunched) {
      return;
    }

    flutterWebView.launch("https://apptreesoftware.com",
        headers: {
          "X-SOME-HEADER": "MyCustomHeader",
        },
        javaScriptEnabled: false,
        toolbarActions: [
          new ToolbarAction("Dismiss", 1),
          new ToolbarAction("Reload", 2)
        ],
        barColor: Colors.green,
        tintColor: Colors.white);
    flutterWebView.onToolbarAction.listen((identifier) {
      switch (identifier) {
        case 1:
          flutterWebView.dismiss();
          break;
        case 2:
          reload();
          break;
      }
    });
    flutterWebView.listenForRedirect("mobile://test.com", true);

    flutterWebView.onWebViewDidStartLoading.listen((url) {
      setState(() => _isLoading = true);
    });
    flutterWebView.onWebViewDidLoad.listen((url) {
      setState(() => _isLoading = false);
    });
    flutterWebView.onRedirect.listen((url) {
      flutterWebView.dismiss();
      setState(() => _redirectedToUrl = url);
    });
  }



  void reload() {
    flutterWebView.load(
      "https://google.com",
      headers: {
        "X-SOME-HEADER": "MyCustomHeader",
      },
    );
  }
}
```

How can I use `launchWebViewExample` in another class?

Comment: Can you please share some code. It's unclear what the problem is. Importing the file with the function should do. If you want to pass the function around there isn't really a difference to fields or other variables.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951989/how-to-reference-another-file-in-dart

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added the code from the file I created.  I'd like to use it to launch the WebView in another file without adding all these lines to each file.

Comment: _ in front of function name will make it private _launchwebview,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Use `mixin` instead of global functions!

### Why does this happen?

> I'm using it over **several different files** and would love to create
> its own file and reference with the _launchwebview function
> anywhere in my app because there are several lines of code needed in
> order to make it work.

Underscored methods are private to a given library. Thus, if we define `_launchwebview` in one file, that function is in a mini-library ([Source](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages)). So, the method will only be accessible within that file. I explored how to expose private methods across files, but found the solution messy. I thus think the question would be better answered using public functions. The problem is implementing a shared function **within different classes** rather than simply providing access.

I've chosen to add this solution for this particular question since the method (launching a web view) would be good to have implemented within every appropriate `Widget` class. Note that extension methods could also work in this case, but Flutter prefers composition over inheritance.

If we want to move a public, i.e. non-underscored method, to a different class without copy-pasting, we could try several outlined approaches. I have detailed the drawbacks of the existing options below.

### Hacky solutions

1. Using the `part` directive enables us to copy the source of one file with a private implementation and use it in another file. But this is discouraged because the technique increases the binary size, goes against the Effective Dart usage guide, and is clearly a code smell because we are copy-pasting the same code.
2. Using global functions doesn't follow Object Oriented programming. Global state breaks the Encapsulation principle. OOP is the best paradigm to use within Dart apps because of the way the language is designed (classes). The top answer recommends global functions, however, this should be a last resort given the powerful language capabilities of Dart.
3. Static functions break encapsulation and the Open-Closed principle. They are hard to integrate with state management solutions because we track the state within instance method contexts. For example, integrating `provider` and other packages like `GetX`.
4. Defining a `Function` as a property of a class can lead to subtle bugs further down the line. For example, we could assign *any* function to this property because there is no **function signature** type checking. Furthermore, this is not a scalable solution with code duplications.

### Solution: Mixins

Dart has inbuilt support for optionally adding functions to a class when we want to reduce duplicated code but avoid extending the whole class ([Source](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#adding-features-to-a-class-mixins)). The `mixin` keyword enables this by mixing a class with some specific logic. We can restrict the `mixin` to a specific subclass with `on` if needed.

### Code example

#### LaunchWebView.dart

```
mixin LaunchWebView on StatelessWidget { // you can also constrain the mixin to specific classes using on in this line.
  void launchWebView() {
    // Add web view logic here. We can add variables to the mixin itself as well.
  }
}
```

#### Usage

```
class ExampleClass extends StatelessWidget with LaunchWebView {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ....
  }

  void testFunction() {
    // We now have access to launchWebView().
    launchWebView();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 152):

You can write a file with just that function, like:

test.dart

```
void launchWebView () {
  print("1234");
}
```

and then import that file like this:

main.dart

```
import "test.dart";

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       launchWebView();
```

It is not really clean, but you can do that.
Alternatively you can use a class with a static method like:

```
class test {
    static void foo() {
        print("1234");
    }
}
```

and then in your code invoke it like that (after the import):

```
test.foo();
```

Comment: I successfully printed a statement, but I'm having a little trouble executing the launchWebView function in the class.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've been thinking btw these 2 options for quite some time. Could you please elaborate on pros/cons btw the two options. The first option doesn't sound like a rule-of-thumb option, right? Although, I don't know why. Could you explain why? On the other hand, I've read that it's best to avoid static methods/variables since they take up memory. But isn't the first option the same story in terms of memory though? In other words if I don't create a class just functions in a file isn't automatically each function static?

Comment: @Antonino Cacace you say top-level functions are not really clean in flutter. but why?
Here is what they say in official docs:
"Note: Consider using top-level functions, instead of static methods, for common or widely used utilities and functionality."
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#adding-features-to-a-class-mixins#static-methods

Comment: This was a great thank you! Helped me on to resolve my blockage!

Answer (score 11):

Or you can just declare all your functions (helpers) inside a class and pass them as an argument to other class.

```
//The class which contains your functions
class HelperFunction{

  //Define your method
  void launchWebView () {
    print("1234");
  }

  //Pass that function to a class
  MyHomePage(launchWebView);

}

//The class which receives the function.
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  //Retrieve the function and store it to a variable of type Function.
  final Function launchWebView;
  MyHomePage(this.launchWebView);
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     //Access that function in State class using widget keyword.
     widget.launchWebView();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do that in different ways:

#### 1. Global function:

Define your function in a file, say `global.dart`:

```dart
void func() => print('Hello');
```

To use it in any file, just call:

```dart
func();
```

#### 2. Static function in a class:

Create a class, say `Foo` and define your function in it:

```dart
class Foo {
  static void func() => print('Hello');
}
```

To use it in any file, just call

```dart
Foo.func();
```

#### 3. Use mixin:

- **If you want to use the function in any class:**

  Create a mixin, say `Bar`:

  ```dart
  mixin Bar {
    void func() => print('Hello');
  }
  ```

  To use it in a class, just use `with` keyword followed by mixin.

  ```dart
  class Baz with Bar {
    void main() => func();
  }
  ```
- **If you want to restrict the mixin from being used with any class:**

  ```dart
  class Foo {}
  ```

  Create a mixin, say `Bar` which is on `Foo`.

  ```dart
  mixin Bar on Foo {
    void func() => print('Hello');
  }
  ```

  To use `Bar` mixin we need to extend `Foo` class because this is what it is on.

  ```dart
  class Baz extends Foo with Bar {
    void main() => func();
  }
  ```

Comment: In global functions part, you can also use `import 'global.dart' as global` in other file and then invoke the function using `global.func();`

Answer (score -10):

You want to declare function on a class level

file foo.dart

```
class Foo {

  static void launchWebView () {};

}
```

file bar.dart

```
import 'foo.dart'
class Bar {

  void someFunction (){
    Foo.launchWebView();
  }


}
```

Comment: how can you directly call method of other class without referencing that class?