# how to call a Function from another Dart file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

i have this funtion which handles my Date and Time picker widget ...Code bellow...

```
Future selectDayAndTimeL(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime? selectedDay = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2021),
        lastDate: DateTime(2030),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) => child!);

    TimeOfDay? selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );

    if (selectedDay != null && selectedTime != null) {
      //a little check
    }
    setState(() {
      selectedDateAndTime = DateTime(
        selectedDay!.year,
        selectedDay!.month,
        selectedDay!.day,
        selectedTime!.hour,
        selectedTime!.minute,
      );
      // _selectedDate = _selectedDay;
    });
    // print('...');
  }
```

initially it was inside my add new task class/dart file "Stateful Widget", and everything was working fine but now i want to also use that function on the Home screen when a button is pressed.

Then i checked a StackOverflow question on [how to call a function from another dart file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836636/how-to-use-functions-of-another-file-in-dart-flutter) which the solution required that i keep the Function on a different dart file then call it from there like this Example

```
void launchWebView () {
  print("1234");
}
```

when i did i was getting an error which i lookedup and it was because of the "setState" in my function so i needed to put it inside a Stateful widget,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SelectDateAndTime extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SelectDateAndTimeState createState() => _SelectDateAndTimeState();
}

class _SelectDateAndTimeState extends State<SelectDateAndTime> {

  DateTime? _selectedDate;
// DateTime _selectedDate;
  DateTime? selectedDateAndTime;

  Future selectDayAndTimeL(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime? selectedDay = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2021),
        lastDate: DateTime(2030),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) => child!);

    TimeOfDay? selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );

    if (selectedDay != null && selectedTime != null) {
      //a little check
    }
    setState(() {
      selectedDateAndTime = DateTime(
        selectedDay!.year,
        selectedDay!.month,
        selectedDay!.day,
        selectedTime!.hour,
        selectedTime!.minute,
      );
      // _selectedDate = _selectedDay;
    });
    // print('...');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

And that was the only difference from my code with the example i followed and i was still getting an error when i tried calling the funtion, and i have checked all the quetions related to clling functions from another dart file / class and none of them had SetState so their solution didn't work for me

This is the error i got when i called just the Function Name
[image]
Bellow s the error i got when i tried to call

```
onPressed: () => selectedDateAndTime!.selectDayAndTimeL(),
```

[image]

what should i do from here?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you originally had a `Statefull` widget, that probably looked something like this:

```dart
class OriginalWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OriginalWidgetState createState() => _OriginalWidgetState();
}

class _OriginalWidgetState extends State<OriginalWidget> {

  DateTime? _selectedDate;
  DateTime? selectedDateAndTime;

  Future selectDayAndTimeL(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime? selectedDay = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2021),
        lastDate: DateTime(2030),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) => child!);

    TimeOfDay? selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );

    if (selectedDay != null && selectedTime != null) {
      //a little check
    }
    setState(() {
      selectedDateAndTime = DateTime(
        selectedDay!.year,
        selectedDay!.month,
        selectedDay!.day,
        selectedTime!.hour,
        selectedTime!.minute,
      );
      // _selectedDate = _selectedDay;
    });
    // print('...');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => selectDayAndTimeL(context));
  } 
}
```

Now, what you want to do is to reuse the logic of your `selectDayAndTimeL` function.

The problem is that both the `selectedDateAndTime` variable and the `setState` method are specific to the Statefull widget `_OriginalWidgetState`.

What you need to do is to modify your `selectDayAndTimeL` function so that it can take those widget-specific stuff as parameters.

So, in essence what you would do is:

1st create the function as a standalone function, for instance in a new dart file. Make sure to remove the widget-specific stuff from the body and leave them as parameters:

```dart
  Future selectDayAndTimeL(BuildContext context, void Function(DateTime) onDateAndTimeSelected) async {
    DateTime? selectedDay = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2021),
        lastDate: DateTime(2030),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) => child!);

    TimeOfDay? selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );

    if (selectedDay != null && selectedTime != null) {
      //a little check
    }
    
      onDateAndTimeSelected(DateTime(
        selectedDay!.year,
        selectedDay!.month,
        selectedDay!.day,
        selectedTime!.hour,
        selectedTime!.minute,
      ));
    // print('...');
  }
```

2nd, on your new Statefull widgets, you may now call this function, make sure that you send the new `onDateAndTimeSelected` parameter:

```dart
class SecondWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondWidgetState createState() => _SecondWidgetState();
}

class _SecondWidgetState extends State<SecondWidget> {
  DateTime? selectedDateAndTime;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => selectDayAndTimeL(context, 
        setState((DateTime selectedValue) {
             selectedDateAndTime = selectedValue;
         } ) 
    ));
  }  
}
```

And then you could just follow the same logic for any other Statefull widget that needs to call your function.

Comment: Please where is the "DateTime? ```selectedDateAndTime;``` " coming from? i was trying to use it then because i tried to put the funtion in a stateful widget named "SelectedDateAndTime" just as you mentioned in the first code snippet, but since we are taking the Stateful widget out and leaving the funtion as a standalone code which name is ```selectedDateAndTimeL``` does that mean i should replace the ```DateTime? selectedDateAndTime;``` with ```DateTime? selectedDateAndTimeL;``` ?... notice the difference is one of them ends with "L" and the other doesn't

Answer (score 0):

setState tells a stateful widget to re-render based on the changed data. In your case you are changing `selectedDateAndTime` and re-building the Widget with updated data.

If you want to update/rebuild a widget from a "remote" function you need to use a callback.

```dart
Future selectDayAndTimeL(BuildContext context,Function(DateTime time) onDateTimeSelected)  async {
    DateTime? selectedDay = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2021),
        lastDate: DateTime(2030),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) => child!);

    TimeOfDay? selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );

    if (selectedDay != null && selectedTime != null) {
      //a little check
    }
    // call the callback here with your calculated data
    onDateTimeSelected(
      DateTime(
        selectedDay!.year,
        selectedDay!.month,
        selectedDay!.day,
        selectedTime!.hour,
        selectedTime!.minute,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Then in the StatefulWidget where you call this function:

```dart
selectDayAndTimeL(BuildContext context,(time) {
  setState(() {
    selectedDateAndTime = time;
  });
});
```

Comment: I should write this code on the onpressed? ```selectDayAndTimeL(BuildContext context,(time) {
  setState(() {
    selectedDateAndTime = time;
  });
});```