# How to check object class type in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

In my code, there is a place where I need to take different actions based on the input class type. 
So I write two lines to check an input object's class type.

```
debugPrint("Let me know the next action: $action");
debugPrint((action is LoadPomodorosAction).toString());
```

And the output is

```
I/flutter (24128): Let me know the next action: Instance of 'LoadPomodorosAction'
I/flutter (24128): false
```

What does this mean?
The object 'action' is "Instance of 'LoadPomodorosAction'" and at the same time its class type is not LoadPomodorosAction .

how do I adjust my code so that I can know the class type of action?
I was suspecting that maybe there is something wrong with runtimetype. But how do I get to know the runtimetype?

Comment: Two different classes can have the same name. Can you reproduce in https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ ? It could also be that you have relative imports in `lib/main.dart` which usually causes such issues.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Splendid!  I stopped using relative imports and using the absolute path instead. Now the (action is LoadPomodorsAction) would return true. Could you explain the reason of this difference to me? I am still confused about why this happens.

Comment: Relative imports should not cause issues among files within `lib/` except `lib/main.dart` (or whatever the entrypoint file is named to start your app)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried replicating your issue and I'm not able to reproduce it. But to explain your inquiry, here is a complete details about the difference between the relative path and absolute path when used in imports as discussed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732897/whats-the-different-between-full-path-and-relative-path-in-dart):

> **package imports**
>
> `'package:...` imports work from everywhere to import files from
> `lib/*`.
>
> **relative imports**
>
> Relative imports are always relative to the importing file. If
> `lib/model/test.dart` imports `'example.dart'`, it imports
> `lib/model/example.dart`.
>
> If you want to import `test/model_tests/fixture.dart` from any file
> within `test/*`, you can only use relative imports because package
> imports always assume `lib/`.
>
> This also applies for all other `non-lib/` top-level directories like
> `drive_test/`, `example/`, `tool/`, ...
>
> **lib/main.dart**
>
> There is currently a known issue with entry-point files in `lib/*`
> like `lib/main.dart` in Flutter.
> https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33076
>
> Dart always assumed entry-point files to be in other top-level
> directories then `lib/` (like `bin/`, `web/`, `tool/`, `example/`,
> ...). Flutter broke this assumption. Therefore you currently must not
> use relative imports in entry-point files inside `lib/`
>
> See also
>
> - [How to reference another file in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951989/how-to-reference-another-file-in-dart?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Previously, [this bug](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33076) was posted in GitHub as an issue between relative and absolute path. It seems that this was resolved per [this GitHub post](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/get_it/issues/49).