# what's the different between full path and relative path in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I develop a flutter app, define serveral models in 'model' package.

Then I declare a class **Example** in 'model' for example.

model/example.dart

```
class Example {
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'class example';
  }
}
```

test_a.dart

```
import 'package:example/model/example.dart'

Example testA() {
  return Example()
}
```

test.dart

```
import 'model/example.dart'
import 'test_a.dart'

test() {
  Example example = testA();
  if (example is Example) {
    print('this class is Example');
  } else {
    print('$example');
  }
}
```

I will get output `class example`

If I change from `import 'model/example.dart'` to `import 'package:example/model/example.dart'` in test.dart, then I will get the output `this class is Example`.

So I'm confused what is different between the full path and relative path in dart.

Comment: Can you please change the location (paths) of the files like `test_a.dart` so that it's clear where they ares stored related to `pubspec.yaml`?
`test_a.dart` sounds like it might be in `test/test_a.dart` but I guess it's `lib/test_a.dart`, it's just confusing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**package imports**

`'package:...` imports work from everywhere to import files from `lib/*`.

**relative imports**

Relative imports are always relative to the importing file.
If `lib/model/test.dart` imports `'example.dart'`, it imports `lib/model/example.dart`.

If you want to import `test/model_tests/fixture.dart` from any file within `test/*`, you can only use relative imports because package imports always assume `lib/`.

This also applies for all other non-`lib/` top-level directories like `drive_test/`, `example/`, `tool/`, ...

**lib/main.dart**

There is currently a known issue with entry-point files in `lib/*` like `lib/main.dart` in Flutter. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33076

Dart always assumed entry-point files to be in other top-level directories then `lib/` (like `bin/`, `web/`, `tool/`, `example/`, ...).
Flutter broke this assumption.
Therefore you currently must not use relative imports in entry-point files inside `lib/`

See also

- [How to reference another file in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951989/how-to-reference-another-file-in-dart?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I needed `import 'package:packageNameFromPubspec/myFileInLib.dart';`

If you change your package name in `pubspec.yaml` run `pub get` to propagate the change.