# Flutter - multiple files for screens?

Tags: flutter

I'm currently learning Flutter development (as well as Dart). It's my first mobile programming language.

I'm curious - is there a way to split screens into .dart files, or do they all have to be in the same main.dart file?

The app I'm building will have a lot of pages, so I don't want to make one giant main.dart file with 20+ different pages.

Is Flutter the right choice if I'm trying to make a large application like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference another file in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951989/how-to-reference-another-file-in-dart)

Comment: I just want to know why you think flutter won't be able to handle your application and why any other platform would because Flutter is built to build cross-platform apps and gives the same performance as the native code and supports 60 fps,hot reload etc, flutter was designed considering that no matter How complex the UI it should be able to build in flutter

Answer (score 15):

You can split your code in as many files as you want. It's encouraged to have as little code as possible in `lib/main.dart` and all the other code split into various files. The only limitation is that code in one file (library) can not access private members of other files.

See [How to reference another file in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951989/how-to-reference-another-file-in-dart) for how to import other Dart files.

Comment: But how to separate 1 screen layout into separate dart file. I have 1 complex screen with 5 tabs. So I want to separate each tab into another dart file. Do these 5 files needs to be a class and has build and also return a scaffold?

Comment: I don't know details but usually you would make parts of your UI a widget and then move the widgets to different dart files and import them from there to where they are used (added to parents). You can have multiple widgets in one file. You can't split a single class into multiple files. You can also refactor the `build()` into functions and move functions to different files, but that's discouraged. Finer-grained widgets are the better approach for Flutter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689435/what-scenarios-is-it-reasonable-to-use-a-function-to-define-a-widget-composition

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-widgets/53234826#53234826

Comment: in fact it works....just like you said just make it as Widget and move it to different dart file. So in this new dart file I use Class not function, it can either be stateless or statefull, and on build(BuildContext context) just return Widget like Container directly... don't use Scaffold anymore. This is why my code didn't work at first time.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take as an example started project generated by the VSCode dart extension.
It looks like this:
`main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return const MaterialApp(
       home: Scaffold(
       body: Center(
       child: Text('Hello World!'),
      ),
    ),
  );
 }
 }
```

Let's create a separate file for the `home` property widget.
First, create `home.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget{
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     // TODO: implement build
     throw UnimplementedError();
  }

}
```

Now we need:

1. to return the `Scaffold` widget from the `Home` `build` method
2. to replace the value of the `home` property of `MaterialApp` with `Home()`.

`home.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget{
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold (
       body: const Center(
       child: Text('Hello World!'),
     )
    );
  }
}
```

`main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';

 void main() {
     runApp(const MainApp());
 }

 class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
     const MainApp({super.key});

    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return const MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
      );
   }
 }
```