# What scenarios is it reasonable to use a function to define a widget composition over a Statelss class?

Tags: flutter

This discussion in github

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19269

discusses the reasons you should use a Stateless class definition over a function component to define your Widget compositions.

```
Widget functionWidgetComposition() => Text('hello');

class MyWidgetComposition extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text('hello');
}
```

If I understood correctly, the reasons to use Stateless are the following...

1. Do I need access to context?
2. Do I care that it won't be rebuilt via hot reload? (or will I remember)
3. Do I need to associate my Widget with a key?
4. Will this Widget ever be a constant?
5. Does this widget ever need to be rebuilt?

It feels quite compelling to always use Stateless as a fairly standard rule but the functional style is so much more concise, especially when you have a few parameters.  I feel functional components will improve readability in my code.  Should I always use Stateless classes then or is it ok to use what React call functional components in some situations?

Comment: I do not think that this is a good question for *StackOverflow* because it is **primarily opinion based**. I read through the thread on GitHub and found out that the question was very nicely answered there already by Flutter team members.

Comment: Took the liberty to add a few more points toward classes on the github discussion

Answer (score 2):

From https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19269#issuecomment-404667287

> Ya, the main difference is in how it links to the Element tree (in
>   that functions don't get references to Elements themselves and won't
>   get triggered to rebuild themselves via the Element tree).
>
> Some other examples:
>
> - If your subtree depends on an InheritedWidget, a StatelessWidget will
>     get surgically be marked to rebuild itself. If you used a function,
>     the widget that gave the function its BuildContext will get rebuilt.
>
>   - A function itself won't get called to rebuild during hot reload. Someone
>       else will have to bring it along. If you just passed a function into
>       runApp at the root of your application, nothing will be rebuilt during
>       hot reload.

For the full discussion see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19269