# Why BuildContext is passed as an argument in the function when the function can work fine without it?

Tags: dart, flutter, mobile-application

The redefined function _buildGridCards(BuildContext context) can work without BuildContext passed to it. For which reason is being passed? Because I tried without any argument and it worked just fine. Is there any advantage of passing BuildContext as an argument even when the code works just fine?

```
 List<Card> _buildGridCards(int count) {
  List<Card> cards = List.generate(
    count,
    (int index) => Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 18.0 / 11.0,
            child: Image.asset('assets/diamond.png'),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 12.0, 16.0, 8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Title'),
                SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                Text('Secondary Text'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );

  return cards;
}

body: GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  childAspectRatio: 8.0 / 9.0,
  children: _buildGridCards(10) // Replace
),
```

Later the function is changed to this:

```
List<Card> _buildGridCards(BuildContext context) {
  List<Product> products = ProductsRepository.loadProducts(Category.all);

  if (products == null || products.isEmpty) {
    return const <Card>[];
  }

  final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
  final NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(
      locale: Localizations.localeOf(context).toString());

  return products.map((product) {
    return Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      // TODO: Adjust card heights (103)
      child: Column(
        // TODO: Center items on the card (103)
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 18 / 11,
            child: Image.asset(
              product.assetName,
              package: product.assetPackage,
             // TODO: Adjust the box size (102)
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 12.0, 16.0, 8.0),
              child: Column(
               // TODO: Align labels to the bottom and center (103)
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                // TODO: Change innermost Column (103)
                children: <Widget>[
                 // TODO: Handle overflowing labels (103)
                 Text(
                    product.name,
                    style: theme.textTheme.title,
                    maxLines: 1,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  Text(
                    formatter.format(product.price),
                    style: theme.textTheme.body2,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }).toList();
}

body: GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  childAspectRatio: 8.0 / 9.0,
  children: _buildGridCards(context) // Changed code
),
```

Comment: We didn't write the function, so why would we know? In a StatefulWidget the context is available as property, so there is no need to pass it. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-widgets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689435/what-scenarios-is-it-reasonable-to-use-a-function-to-define-a-widget-composition about whether it's a good idea to use a function to build a widget tree.

Comment: A context is nothing else but a reference to the location of a Widget within the tree structure of all the Widgets which are built.  See also this for more information https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/06/widget---state---context---inheritedwidget/