# How to test main method in bin folder (Dart standalone command-line app)

Tags: unit-testing, dart, command-line

I have written a simple command-line Dart app. The functionality of the app is in file app.dart located in the bin directory.

**bin/app.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';
void main(List<String> args) {
   //(...)
}
```

I'd like to test the main method with unit tests. For this purpose I have a file app_test.dart in the test directory

**test/app_test.dart**

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:app/app.dart';

void main() {
  test('main method runs through with exit code 0', () {
    //I'd like to run the main method from bin/app.dart here
  });
}
```

How can I refer to the main method in bin/app.dart from the file test/app.dart to run the main method for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is apparently to use a relative path import instead of a package import. So I changed the line

```
import 'package:app/app.dart';
```

in file **test/app_test.dart**

to

```
import '../bin/app.dart' as app;
```

This enabled being able to call the main method with

```
app.main();
```

from the test file.

I couldn't not easily find a reference to this behaviour in the official documents, but this Stackoverflow answer came to rescue: [How to reference another file in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951989/how-to-reference-another-file-in-dart)