# Dart module import

Tags: dart, module, package, libraries

I´m new to DART/FLUTTER. I read the documentation and lot´s of posts, but am still confused about the concept of dart imports. The documentation on ***dart.dev*** is much about building and using ***packages***, but not very clear on general aspects of 'import'. Some explanations are spread somewhere in the text. But I´m still missing a *clear language definition*. There is a [DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf), which is not helpful to understand the basic concepts.

On dart.dev we find two types of import:

- import 'dart:xxx' -> Multi-platform libraries, Native platform libraries, Web platform libraries. So this are the core libraries !?
- import 'package:xxx' -> libraries from packages. All kinds of third party libraries we can install from **pub.dev**.

So, that´s pretty much all we find about imports. There is some explanation in [the language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries), a post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951989/how-to-reference-another-file-in-dart) and [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_libraries.htm).

Is there a more detailed explanation or reference of the **concepts and syntax of dart imports** somewhere?

---

***What I found:***

- You can use libraries similar to code modules in JS, beside some differences in the use of namespaces. The library file has to start with 'library + name', definitions are imported directly, as long as you do not use 'import .. as'.
- definitions beginning with an underscore are not exported

---

***Questions:***

- can I use an absolute path for a library? Just found relative path definitions
- can we use URL´s in a path definition to read a library from the web?
- what happens, if a library is imported multiple times in different modules?
- can we have different libraries with the same name, but different path?
- are there any limitations in the data types we can use in a library file?

*Maybe I simply missed a source, but from other posts it seems, I´m not the only one looking for this information.*